# Convert a number in attribute table to binary

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I would like to convert whole integers from decimal to binary in ArcGIS using the field calculator.

I am looking for the equivalent of [DEC2BIN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/dec2bin-HP005209053.aspx) excel command.

All values are 255 or below so 8 bit is fine.

It must have 0 padding to the left. So for example 4 must be 00000100.

I can do it by exporting the attribute table to Excel and using the Dec2Bin command in Excel and rejoin the data but I would like it in a model so want to use the field calculator.

Dec2Bin (Value, 8) works in Excel.

Attached is how I would like it to look when complete.

[image]

So basically change the value to and 8 digit binary value stored as a text field with leading 0s so all field have 8 values.

I found this code in arcscripts but cannot get it to function.

Dim valI as integer
Dim valB as string
Dim x as integer
valI = [fieldName]
for x = 7 to 0 step -1
  if valI >= 2^x then
    valB = valB & 1
    valI = valI - 2^x
  else
    valB = valB & 0
  end if
Next
valB = valB & "00000000"

fieldName = 
valB

Comment: Just to clarify I'm looking for a field calculator expression to change the [value] to binary as shown above in the 'textbin field. This was done via an excel join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many threads on this issue, here are some examples

```
>>> bin(100)
'0b1100100'
>>> bin(4)
'0b100'
>>> getBin = lambda x, n: x >= 0 and str(bin(x))[2:].zfill(n) or "-" + str(bin(x))[3:].zfill
>>> getBin(4,8)
'00000100'
```

Comment: To expand on this: using the field calculator, set the parser to Python, then use the expression `bin(!VALUE!)[2:].zfill(8)`, where VALUE is the name of the field you want to convert.